# ffmpegで動画を生成し、それをrtmpサーバーに配信するとmp3ファイルの再生が終わるまでは問題ないが、mp3ファイルの再生が終わると突然CPU使用率が10倍以上になり配信ができなくなる

Tags: ffmpeg

下記のコマンドを使用しています。

```bash
ffmpeg -re -i live.mp3 -loop 1 -i live.jpg -r 30000/1000 -g 60 -c:v libx264 -x264-params -preset ultrafast -c:a copy -f flv rtmp://<youtube>
```

曲が流れている最中は`speed=1x`となっているのですが、終わった瞬間に`speed=3.1x`のように突然加速し、CPUを枯渇します。
これについて類似の質問を探しましたが、探した限りでは見つかりませんでした。

Comment: 映像入力に対して`-re`オプション指定すると挙動に変化あるでしょうか？（`-loop 1`直前に`-re`を指定）